# Using IIS for URL redirects on published project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I have a ASP.net MVP application I'm building in Visual Studio.

The published project domain will be something like http://example.com/ProjectName

I have a ton of of URLs I am using when running the project locally that look something like the following.

```
<a href="/foo/bar">Test</a>
```

These work fine locally, but when I publish the project they break. For instance, this is what it will redirect to on my published version:

http://example.com/foo/bar

When I want it to be:

http://example.com/ProjectName/foo/bar

Can I fix this using IIS and the rewrite module? My attempt is below.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="./ProjectName/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: @mxmissile Ah that makes sense. What about if my urls are dynamically built in javascript? If I try to do something like 'var url = "~/api/test"' it will attempt to go to http://example.com/~/api/test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using razor, change your urls to `"~/foo/bar"`. If your urls are generated in js, you can mix the two:

```
<script>
  var url = '@Url.Content("~/api/test")';

  or

  var url = '@Url.Action(...)';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<rule name="Index Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^ProjectName/" negate="true" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_URL}" pattern="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="/ProjectName{C:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Note the negate="true" attribute. So, this rule will be active only for the resources like "/foo/bar" and not for "/ProjectName/*"

Comment: Thank you. This may also be a solution but I was way overthinking it to begin with.